# Error creating a symbolic link

Tags: linux, hyperlink, symlink

I want to create a symbolic link in linux, but I always get the same error.

First I create the symbolic link this way:

```
ln -s preproceso/genomas_12juny/Bacteria wwwprueba/webproves/g3/genomas/
```

What I want is to create a symbolic link in `wwwprueba/webproves/g3/genomas/` named "Bacteria" and with the content of `preproceso/genomas_12juny/Bacteria/`

When I try to open the link created I get the following error:

```
The link "Bacteria" is broken. Do you want to move it to the trash?
The link cannot be used because its destination "preproceso/genomas_12juny/Bacteria" does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Either, use the full path to specify the link, or use a path relative to where the link will be created.

Comment: both paths are in the directory I am. What I'd have to do different in order to do it woth relative paths?

Comment: @Ingrid: Try: `ln -s ../../../../preproceso/genomas_12juny/Bacteria wwwprueba/webproves/g3/genomas/`

Comment: @choroba is right, full path is NEEDED and MANDATORY, for symbolic link to work.